# High varying discharge rate

Tags: linux, power-management, powertop

I got an Asus N76VB notebook. On Windows I can easily stay on battery for 3-4 hours in powersave mode, but on Linux (first Ubuntu 14.04, currently Fedora 20) the battery's discharge rate varies from 10 watt to 40 watt (~25 watt mean) on powersave mode with backlight on the lowest possible value, resulting in 1-2 hours of battery life.

I've tried:

- Installing Bumblebee (with nVidia drivers)
- Installing TLP (with most powersaving configuration)
- Enable all tunables in powertop (already done by TLP)

Powertop shows the following:

[image: powertop]

I've no idea of any other causes of the high discharge rate. What's an average discharge rate?

Currently I've only opened a terminal and Google Chrome window with this page and a YouTube video, on a almost clean Fedora installation, but it also happens with Firefox or without YouTube video.

Any help would be appreciated!